# Reload cache image after update

Tags: javascript, php, caching

I want to reload the cached image after update.
I created it with timestamp like below:

```
echo "<img src=../thumbnail.jpg?" . time() . ">";
```

But this image show in multi pages and I have to set `time()` for all.
This `time()` change url of image, so every load pictures reloaded as if it was not.

My images can update from multi users. If I set `time()` for all url of image every reload, it affects the performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`time()` returns the current time, so it will be different every time the page loads and won't do what you want.

If your framework has a system for versioning static assets, you should use that. Otherwise you can use `filemtime()`, which returns the timestamp for when a file last changed, as in this example:

```
<img src="<?=$path?>?v=<?=filemtime($path)?>">
```

That way it will only change when the timestamp for the file is changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a task runner, such as Grunt, Gulp or another similar, you could add in a task to add a hash of the image content to its filename as well as update the files that reference the images/css/js/...

(You could also optimise the image to completely automate the workflow.)

**Grunt** - [grunt-cache-bust](https://github.com/hollandben/grunt-cache-bust)

**Gulp** - [gulp-cachebust](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-cachebust)